# How to add shadow to text inside fabricjs Textbox

Tags: fabricjs

When you add shadow to fabricjs Textbox it is not added to text but to the Textbox object. When i try to add shadow using setSelectionStyles it doesnt have any effect.

I tried this:

```
    var myshadow = new fabric.Shadow({
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
        blur: "6",
        offsetX: "4",
        offsetY: "4",
    });
    
    actobj.setSelectionStyles({ shadow: myshadow });
```

Is there a way how to add shadow to text inside fabric Textbox ?